# In boost::graph, how can I get the adjacent vertex given a directed adjacency graph, vertex, and out edge index?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I have an adjacency_list graph defined as follows:

`struct VertexProperties{
    std::string name;
    ...
};
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
                              boost::vecS,
                              boost::directedS,
                              VertexProperties> GraphType;
typedef GraphType::vertex_descriptor VertexType;`

Given a graph, vertex, and out edge index, how can I get the adjacent vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

`typedef 
boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::out_edge_iterator
out_edge_iterator;

typedef 
std::pair<out_edge_iterator, out_edge_iterator>
out_edge_iterator_range;

out_edge_iterator_range range = boost::out_edges(current_vertex, graph);
if (out_index > range.second - range.first){
    // out_index is invalid
}
out_edge_iterator iter = range.first + row;

VertexType out_vertex = iter->m_target;`